# (TypeScript) Create type from function argument type

Tags: typescript

I've the following code:

```
const Config = {
    param1: 10,
    param2: true,
};

type C = typeof Config;

function Func1<K extends keyof C>(a: { parameter: K; value: C[K] }) { }
```

Now if I call `Func1` I'll get an error if I use the wrong type for the parameter, e.g:

```
Func1({ parameter: 'param2', value: 23 });
                                 // ^ Error: not a boolean, we're good
```

**Question:**

Is it possible to create a new type dynamically based on the function argument type, like that:

```
type T0<K extends keyof C> = {
    parameter: K;
    value: {
        param1: number;
        param2: boolean;
    }[K];
}

function Func2<K extends keyof C>(a: T0<K>): void { }
Func2({ parameter: 'param2', value: 42 });
                                 // ^ Error: not a boolean, we're good
```

Here instead I'd like to create the type `T0` dynamically based on the function argument type.

I tried the following, but I loose the type checking for the second parameter:

```
function Func3(a: Parameters<typeof Func1>[0]): void { }
Func3({ parameter: 'param2', value: 23 });
                                 // ^ No Error, we're NOT good
```

The type of the parameter in this case is :

```
a: {
    parameter: "param1" | "param2";
    value: number | boolean;
}
```

I'd like still to be able to restrict the type of the second parameter (in this case `value`) based on the first parameter.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAwuAZgSwOYwLwwN4FgBQMRMADgIYBOZAtgIwBcMtADADQHGmU0BMjUFAK4BTdvgC+AbgIEoATxLD4mGPMUhE8JGmn4Z+RILDAoycDABiR4LQA8AaRjCAHlGFgAJhBgBrYXI14AD4ACjJGbC4qamE3CkZ7SRgANzIAGxFGOABtewBdGHEAShxCgitjWhDI8mjY4XiYAHJa3ibWFPTMmAAWHkKi3VkFJQAVZgcnV3cvX39AuCCVPEJiVpi4hN1OVIzhCI5ONe46RjBBagAjBu2jonW+GEuQEDThMjBbonFcvN1xfSGYymcwVYA8SYuNyebx+AKaRZhRjjBxBIqMZIgZAeUoA-BgnjVKI0eqNFonHjtTp7Rh9AZDPQGawgsCWawAZiRMAACidSRBbGphIEwbQgtlmHl0SksTjIniwZyanzNs0HlTdt06cVdEA)

---

So in other words, when we use `type T1 = typeof Func1`, we get the following type:

```
type T1 = <K extends "param1" | "param2">(a: {
    parameter: K;
    value: {
        param1: number;
        param2: boolean;
    }[K];
}) => void
```

... is it possible to create a new type like below from the type above? :

```
type T0<K extends "param1" | "param2"> = {
    parameter: K;
    value: {
        param1: number;
        param2: boolean;
    }[K];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately [no](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22617#issuecomment-375123727). `Func1` is generic and TypeScript currently cannot infer generic types.

> function type parameters are erased to their constraints and we infer from those

The same is happening when you use `Parameters<typeof Func1>`. Parameters of `Func1` erased to their constrains (i.e. `value` becomes `value: number | boolean`) and this type is returned.

The only way is to use `T0<K>` explicitly as you've already does.